# text on iPad looks blurry

Tags: objective-c, uifont

i have created the iPhone app
on iPhone it works perfectly but when i run it on my ipad and move it to 2x 
text in my apps display blurry
is there any solution where on my retina ipad text also looks smooth as on iPhone

Comment: try `someView.layer.shouldRasterize = false;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue few month ago, it is because your application is only for iPhone. Please do not worry about this issue because this problem will only on iPad (non-Retina). and for iPad with Retina I will work fine. You will see the smooth font on retina (iPad). and If you want the same on iPad (non-retina) then go for a universal app. I solve this using universal app.

Comment: but on Retina also it looks blurry